# how to open dynamically formed hyperlinked images to popup window

Tags: javascript, php, html

The following code show the dynamically called images but I want to open images in popup window as well. Right now only the first image has been opened on any image click event.

```
  <div class="row">
    <?php
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $ofr = "SELECT * FROM `offers` where center = '$city' ";
        $ResOfr = mysqli_query($con, $ofr);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($ResOfr))
        { ?>
            <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-top:23px;">
                <a  href="#fancybox-content" class="open_popup1">
                    <img src="./images/offers/<?php echo $row['offer'] ?>"/>
                </a>
                <div id="fancybox-content" style="display:none;">
                    <a href="#" id="close_popup1" style="text-align:center;     margin-left:47%">
                   <img src="images/close.png"/>
                </a>
              <img src="./images/offers/<?php echo $row['offer'] ?>"/>
        </div>  

        </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: $(".open_popup1").click(function(){
        $("#fancybox-content").css("display", "block");
  });

Comment: You have to generate unique class name as per your records number in while loop  <a  href="#fancybox-content" class="open_popup1"> <a  href="#fancybox-content" class="open_popup2"> <a  href="#fancybox-content" class="open_popup3">......

Comment: i tried that... everything is working fine.. but when I click on any images in popup only the first record has seen. I want the popup window to show the clicked image.